# Utiliser "interloquant" comme adjectif?

Tags: adjectifs, participe-présent

Bonjour, je trouve en ligne plusieurs usages de "interloquant" comme adjectif, plus ou moins utilisé comme synonyme de "choquant" / "qui interloque".
Cet usage est il valide ? Je ne trouve que le participe présent de "interloquer" dans le dictionnaire, et une professeur de français que je connais m'indique que c'est une faute.

Comment: Faute aujourd'hui, bon usage demain...

Comment: @Frank C'est tellement employé (suffit de voir le nombre occurrences de l'emploi du mot comme adjectif dans google books) qu'on ne peut pas dire que ce soit une faute - tout court.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il me semble absurde de considérer cet usage comme une faute. Il est certes rare, mais on trouve des occurrences de formes accordées, donc adjectivales, d'interloquant et elles n'ont rien de choquant.

> Quelque interloquantes que fussent plus d’une fois ces bouffées de la folle du logis, à tout prendre, Hook arrivait toujours à bon port, et de sa part tout passait; pour lui le sacramentel *shocking* n’existait plus : l’éblouissante verve faisait glisser sur ce que le formalisme ailleurs aurait trouvé répréhensible.
>
> Louis Gabriel Michaud, *Biographie universelle ancienne et moderne*, tome 19, 1857.

> Les œuvres de Scottie sont de toutes celles connues … au nombre des plus chargées, des plus hautement cérébrales, des plus interloquantes et fascinantes. Elles sont si étranges qu'à les rencontrer sans être informé de leur auteur on serait probablement tenté de les lier à une déraison fiévreusement aberrante et une humeur d'aliénation, cependant que l’homme exemplaire qu'elles ont pour auteur … est aussi peu fou qu'il se peut, à moins que ce soit être fou qu'être sage et clairvoyant au point qu'il est. Je ne crois pas avoir de ma vie rencontré homme de si grand savoir.
>
> Jean Dubuffet, 1965.

> Si complexes que soient les processus électroniques, suffisent-ils à rendre compte des phénomènes de langage ? À première entente, oui, puisque les trois réactions physico-chimiques, organismales et linguistiques sont toutes censées relever d'un processus électro-colloïdal, c'est-à-dire électronique. L'histoire des sujets parlants, écoutants, interloquants ne joue-t-elle donc aucun rôle ?
>
> Michel Van Schendel, *Rebonds critiques : questions de littérature : essais*, 1992.